# Вариант отклонения правки не соответствует правке

Tags: поддержка, метки, предлагаемые-правки

При утверждении [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/104209) мне для выбора был предложен в том числе вариант:

> - несоответствующие метки
>
> Правка содержит новые метки, которые не помогают определить тему вопроса. Метки должны упрощать понимание того, о чем вопрос, а не только то, что он содержит.

хотя правка и не содержала вовсе исправления меток. Это нормально?

К сожалению скриншота не сделал, ну и для отклонения был выбран другой вариант (который посчитал правильным).